# zend-log: Send errors to stderr, anything else to stdout

Tags: php, logging, zend-framework3, zend-log

Currently my logger is set up like this:

```
$logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter(new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://stdout'));
```

The downside: Both `$logger->err()` and `$logger->info()` now print to `stdout`. However, I’d like the former to print to `stderr`? Can I assign certain writers to priorities? So anything `<= Zend\Log\Logger::ERR` ends up in `stderr` while anything else in `stdout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many writers as you want, and filter them by their priority.

```php
// Add ERROR writer
$logger = new Logger();
$errorWriter = new Stream('php://stdout');
// Filter logs only for ERROR priority
$errorWriter->addFilter(new Priority(Logger::ERR, '='));
$logger->addWriter($errorWriter);

// Add INFO writer
$infoWriter = new Stream('php://stderr');
// Filter logs only for INFO priority
$infoWriter->addFilter(new Priority(Logger::INFO, '='));
$logger->addWriter($infoWriter);
```

You can find more information in the docs:

- [Writers](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/writers/)
- [Writers priority notice](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/writers/#distinction-between-priority-in-the-queue-of-writers-and-the-filter-priority)
- [Writer filters](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/filters/)